# Class association necessity

Tags: class, uml

The diagram below is based on these facts:

- A citizen may make a claim / reclamation on pollutions
- An administrator will send the reclamation by type to the appropriate agency / organization, and it will respond with a diagnostic report
- This report will be sent by the administrator, to another organization, for the estimation of the solution (costs, etc.).

My problem is to how can I show that `Admin` will send the claim to an agency? Do I have to make an association between `Organization` and `Reclamation`?

[image]

Comment: What is the meaning of `DiagnosticAgent`? I assume one that is sitting in `Organization`.

Comment: yes.. it's someone in the organization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your requirements include that the communication between the `Admin` and the `Organization` is to be documented, then you need to take care of this in your class diagram. And, in fact, you already have an item for this: the `NotifyOrganization` association class. Notice, however, that it's not a good idea to use the questionable UML concept of an association class, which does not have a clear semantics and is confusing. This seems to be confirmed by your flawed modeling of the multiplicities of the `NotifyOrganization` association, which must not be one-to-one (or 1 to 0..1), but rather many-to-many (* to *).

So, better replace the `NotifyOrganization` association class with an ordinary class (possibly with an improved name such as `Notification`) and attach it to `Admin` and `Organization` with two many-to-one associations such that each notification is linked to exactly one admin and one Organization.

Notice that a notification represents a (communication/message) event, so `Notification` represents an event type. It*s quite common in business information models to have both object types and event types, both as classes in a UML class diagram.

Answer (score 1):

> ...how can I show that `Admin` will send the claim to an agency?

`UML Class Diagram` is not show-everything document. In order to document that admin will send claim to agency you can document it effectively using [UML Sequence Diagram](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams.html) or some other behavior diagram

> ...do I have to make an association between `Organization` and `Reclamation`?

No, if the agency does not need to care about who exactly delivered the claim or what's the person's role (e.g. "admin"), then you don' have to add it to the class model (and show some association) at all

> ...diagram...based on these facts...

In order to describe the overall process in a one-page style picture, you (and your business partners) can find very useful the [Business Process Model and Notation (BPMN)](http://camunda.org/bpmn/examples/) graphical language in addition to `UML`